# embed javascript ojbect in jade template from controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using jade to do all my rendering, and I"m passing my data from my controller in node into my page template.

I want to add an object inline with javascript... I have a variable app in a js file, and I want to include more data into that app object. I have the following:

```
 script(type="text/javascript")
    app.stations = !{page_data.station_info}
```

Which I would want to output as

```
 script(trype="text/javascript")
   app.stations = [{my json object}]
```

But instead it's rendering like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     <app class="stations">= [my json object]
 </app>
```

EDIT:
After an hour of research I figured it out: (you need to put a . after script

```
 script.
   app.stations = JSON STUFF
```

Comment: you can post a answer to your own question and mark as correct. This can help other in future.

Answer (score 1):

After an hour of research I was able to figure it out... You do script. and then write your javascript normally. See below

```
 script.
    app.stations = JSON STUFF
```